# Weblogic 12c does not allow to use net.sf.jasperreports-jasperreports dependency greater than 6.18.1

Tags: jasper-reports, weblogic, weblogic12c, jackson-databind

I am using **Weblogic 12c** to **deploy web application** which is **developed in Spring Boot 2.7.12** where to generate pdf I am trying to use latest (below) maven dependancy.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
     <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.20.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Here **everything is working fine in local** editor (Eclipse) and PDF getting generated successfully but when I **deploy build(WAR) of same project in local weblogic 12c server it gives me following error.**

```
[]>>[]:01 Jun 2023  14:44:40:[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext Method: refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;
[]>>[]:01 Jun 2023  14:44:40:[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener Method: logMessage

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[]>>[]:01 Jun 2023  14:44:40:[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter Method: report

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:176)

The following method did not exist:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;

The calling method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper, was loaded from the following location:
    zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/<<ServerName>>/tmp/_WL_user/<<ApplicationName>>/cocg8y/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.13.5.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.class

The called method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper, is available from the following locations:
    zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/<<ServerName>>/tmp/_WL_user/ApplicationName/cocg8y/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.13.5.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper: file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/<<ServerName>>/tmp/_WL_user/ApplicationName/cocg8y/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.13.5.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper: file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec: file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeCodec: file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar
```

I have already tried with jasperreports version 6.18.1 and deploy application on weblogic 12c it is working fine but the version 6.18.1 having vulnerabilities so it requires to upgrade.

Can anybody share your views on above, please?